# Optimized css option in angualr 6 components, common css in styles.css or per component css

Tags: html, css, angular6

We have some common style in style.css,
and these classes are used throughout project in different components .

```
.bckMagentaClr{
    background-color: #e20074 !important;
}
.fntClrWhite{
    color: #fff !important;
}
.f16p
{
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
.Arial{
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

What is the best option use 

1. these classes seperately like below whereever corresponding style is needed

```
<div class ="f16p  Arial bckMagentaClr fntClrWhite">
  Set of text comes here.
</div>
```

OR

2. create a class for this particular component and use it.

   .txtDiv{
             background-color: #e20074 !important; 
             color: #fff !important;
             font-size: 16px !important;
             font-family: Arial;
             }

   ```
   <div class ="txtDiv">
     Set of text comes here.
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make a common class for css you want apply that div is good practice.

```css
.common-class{
 background-color: #e20074 !important;
 color: #fff !important;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class ="common-class">
  Set of text comes here.
</div>
```

Comment: even if that styles are part of common css.?

Comment: which is recommended 1 or 2

Comment: i suggest for second option.